# Why is Copy constructor called with rvalue

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

In the below code, even though Account(20, "Dave") at Line2 is rvalue, why is the copy constructor called (Line1), instead of compiler throwing error? In case of normal functions receiving rvalue, if we use lvalue reference as input parameter, compiler throws error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Account
{
private:
    int num;
    std::string name;
public:
        Account(int lnum, std::string lname) : num {lnum}, name {lname}
        {
            std::cout << "\n3arg constr";
        }
        
        Account(const Account &a) : Account{a.num, a.name}          //Line1
        {
            std::cout << "\nCopy Constr";
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Account> myVec {};
    myVec.push_back(Account(20, "Dave"));     //Line2
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Due to the fact that the `Account` hasn't defined a move ctor (?).

Comment: An lvalue-reference-to-const can bind to rvalues.

Comment: *"In case of normal functions receiving rvalue, if we use lvalue reference as input parameter, compiler throws error."* -- could you give an example of this? As far as I'm aware, rvalues can bind to `const` lvalue references in both normal functions and constructors. (Without the `const`, there is an error, again in both normal functions and constructors.)

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on answers supplied below?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *rvalues are moved, lvalues are copied*. But when there's no according move operation, **rvalues are copied** as well.

The compiler will synthesize a move constructor only for such class that doesn't define any of its own copy-control members (copy-constructor, copy-assignment, or destructor), and if all the non-`static` members can be moved.

If a class doesn't have a move operation, the corresponding copy operation will be used, through normal function matching (`T&&` can convert to `const T&`).

Unlike copy operations, a move operation won't be implicitly defined as deleted function. A copy is simply used instead.

As for the `push_back()`. Vector provides guarantees that is something goes wrong in process of the `push_back()`, the `vector`, to which we push, will be left unchanged, in the absence of `noexcept` move constructor for a class, a copy is used instead,

Answer (score 0):

What you have in `Account(const Account &a)` is an lvalue reference *to const*. Const lvalue references *can bind* to rvalues. Quoting the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#:%7E:text=lvalue%20references%20to%20const%20can%20extend%20the%20lifetimes%20of%20temporary%20objects%20too,%20but%20they%20are%20not%20modifiable%20through%20them) (***emphasis mine***)

> Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary
> objects (***note, lvalue references to const can extend the lifetimes of
> temporary objects too, but they are not modifiable through them***):

```
struct Foo{};

void bar(Foo && f) {}

void baz(Foo const&) {}

void qux(Foo&) {}

int main() {
    bar(Foo{}); //rvalue reference binds to rvalue
    baz(Foo{}); //const rvalue reference binds to rvalue
    //Error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Foo&' to an rvalue of type 'Foo'
    // qux(Foo{}); 
}
```